# Php:Creating PDF file

Tags: php, pdf

I'm wondering is this is possible or not?
Suppose i have div containing 10 Questions,Options and Answers.
Now,if user want to copy content of that div he has to manually select and copy the content using mouse and paste on his editor(Ms Word or some other editors).

But what i want is when user clicks the download button the content gets copied to the pdf(or other file) file and can be downloaded.

Comment: yes u can do it. .just go through `fpdf`

Comment: please, check the answer you liked, this is only good for your own reputation later..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fpdf` for that

[Here's](http://www.phpjabbers.com/create-pdf-file-with-php-php36.html) a nice tutorial of how to create a pdf file using PHP

[Reference](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Answer (score 1):

i think, you need `fpdf` lib.

to create txto other similiar file from the content of the page:

- open/create file
- read_page = read the page content
- file_put_content(read_page)
- file is ready to download

Answer (score 1):

`FPDF` is probably the best library to create PDF's in PHP

Check out fpdf website here :
http://www.fpdf.org/

Best for
Multiple layers of text/images
Watermarks
Barcodes much more

Do check out the Scripts section in the website

Answer (score 1):

Great PDF lib for creating PFDs is mpdf just try example, you would be amazed how easy it is: http://www.mpdf1.com/